# Comparando Array imprindo PHP

Tags: php

Tenho dois array um que me da limite e o outro que vem com as informações do banco de dados.

```
$limite = array("06","07","08","09","10","11","12");
$mes = array("09","10","11","12");
```

ele gera uma linha da tabela.
quando comparados quero que imprima os valor da $mes quando tiver no mesmo índice do limite. E quando não achar o valor sai zero. ate fiz porem ele imprime os valores vazios no final e não no começo como eu quero

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td>09</td>
       <td>10</td>
       <td>11</td>
       <td>12</td>
   </tr>
```

aqui esta o codigo que eu fiz porem so imprime no final em vez do começo

```
 for($a=0;$a<count($semestre2);$a++){
     $mes = array_search($mes[$a], $limite);
     if($mes){
         echo '<td>'.$dateRange[$a].'_p'].'</td>';             
     }else{
         echo '<td></td>';           
     }
 }
```

Comment: Os dados sempre retornarão assim ordenados? Por exemplo: limite(06,07,08...) e o mês tbm ordenado, tipo: (09,10,11)?  Em nenhum momento isso possa vir acontecer, ex: `array("06","09","10","11","12")`, veja que vei do banco, (06,09...)

Comment: Quem é o $semestre2? Pois vc conta ele para montar as celulas da tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se os dados retornarem sempre ordenados, assim como definido na sua pergunta e que a **lista de *limite*** é a responsável por montar as células da tabela, pela sua lógica de por `0`. Me faz pensar que em nenhum momento isso irá acontecer:

```
$limite = array("11","12");
$mes = array("09","10","11","12");
```

Pois o resultado seria esse:

```
11  12
```

Então com isso em mente, **lista de *limite*** para a montagem e comparação. Resolveria assim:

```
$limite = array("06","07","08","09","10","11","12");
$mes = array("09","10","11","12");
    
echo '<table><tr>';

foreach($limite as $chave => $valor):
    if(in_array($valor, $mes)):
        echo "<td>$valor</td>";
    else:
        echo "<td>0</td>";
    endif;
endforeach;

echo '</tr></table>';
```

Saída:

```
0   0   0   09  10  11  12
```

Agora se em algum momento isso vir acontecer:

```
$limite = array("04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12");
$mes = array("05","08","09","10","11","12");
```

Você teria isso aqui como resultado:

```
0   05  0   0   08  09  10  11  12
```